# Capture User Input after a Certain Point (BASH)

Tags: bash, user-input

I'm creating a bash script that takes a user input, like a link: http://thisismylink.com/stuff/morestuff/downloadstuff.deb.

I want to be able create a variable for the input AFTER the last "/". I've found plenty of scripts to stop reading, but I need to only pull the data after the last / - so that $somevariable=downloadstuff.deb.

Thanks for your help/guidance/direction.

- Jason

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with bash string manipulation functions

```
$ S=http://thisismylink.com/stuff/morestuff/downloadstuff.deb
$ V=${S##*/}
$ echo $V
downloadstuff.deb
```

You can see more of them in http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Comment: Hi, thanks - I had previously tried a version of that, this is what I have:

    echo Please insert the link
    read link 
    echo -n This is your input: $link
    $S=$link
    $V=${S##*/}
    echo $V

But it doesn't work - get a lot of different errors

Comment: I can't get this to work in the comment section - here's the code I used: http://pastebin.com/bi1uVzDJ


So this works, to an extent, however I get:

line 6: downloadstuff.deb, command not found

Comment: Hi @Hawk ! you are setting var with `$V=...`, but it should be set with `V=...`. Also, the last `$echo. should be `echo`